# HTML Parser for C

Tags: c, xml-parsing, libxml2

I am looking for an easy to use html parser library. Currently I am trying to setup libxml2 but am running into frustrating problems. The IDE I am using is Pelles C, I took the windows files for libxml2 and put them in the appropriate folders (headers in the correct header area, binaries in bin, libs in libraries etc.) but still whenever I try to compile a program the compiler just tells me that every libxml2 function I call is undefined. For example:

Linker Flags:

`-subsystem:console -machine:amd64 kernel32.lib advapi32.lib delayimp64.lib Ws2_32.lib libxml2.lib`

Code:

```
static void print_element_names(xmlNode * a_node)
{
xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;

for(cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next) 
{
    if (cur_node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) 
    {
        printf("node type: Element, name: %s\n", cur_node->name);
    }
    print_element_names(cur_node->children);
}
}

int main(void)
{
xmlDoc *doc = NULL;
xmlNode *root_element = NULL;

LIBXML_TEST_VERSION
doc = xmlReadFile("XMLFILE"/*XML_FILE PUT HERE*/, NULL, 0);
if (doc != NULL) printf("error: could not parse file");
root_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
print_element_names(root_element);
xmlFreeDoc(doc);
xmlCleanupParser();

return 0;
}
```

just gives me the following errors when trying to compile:

```
POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol 'xmlCheckVersion'.
POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol 'xmlReadFile'.
POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol 'xmlDocGetRootElement'.
POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol 'xmlFreeDoc'.
POLINK: error: Unresolved external symbol 'xmlCleanupParser'.
POLINK: fatal error: 5 unresolved external(s).
```

this whole situation is driving me insane, if anybody could help me resolve this issue or perhaps suggest an easier to setup html parser I would immensely appreciate it.

Comment: HTML or XML? HTML is not XML.

Comment: Then why are you trying to use an XML library to parse it?

Comment: Well if you want the honest answer, I have no idea and it seems that I made an embarrassing mistake. I am now searching for an html parser, thanks for setting me on the right track.

Comment: No problem. Using libxml is still a valid question, but I just wanted to alert you that it probably won't solve your problem of parsing html. Note that parsing html is *a lot* harder than parsing xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those errors are related to the linking stage: whatever library you used would give you the same issues.

Unless you did install a wrong package (e.g. 64 bits library instead of 32, or vice versa).

For XML parsing, libxml2 is quite a useful tool, it is pretty fast and quite powerful. Seeing as how you've already started with that, I'd try to solve the linker problems instead.

Comment: the linking stage meaning what? I'm somewhat confused as to what could be causing this issue then, I'm on a 64bit machine, running the 64bit Pelles C ide? So if it's a linking stage how could I resolve that? I feel completely in the dark at this point.

Comment: The Pelles IDE will first convert the C source into object code, and apparently does this without errors. Then it will try to resolve the references by looking into available libraries -- and there's where it's failing. With GCC I sometimes have to specify libraries in a different order; try that, maybe it's the same with Pelles. Otherwise, I'd check if the binary lib file is correct for the architecture (BTW, shouldn't it be a DLL?). Sorry, I don't know what else to try. But rest assured it's no fault of libxml2 :-)

Comment: I know for a fact that it's something I'm doing wrong but I just don't know either :P

Comment: The symbol names appear to be correct and match the library (ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/libxml2-2.7.8.win32.zip). Try to change the linker flags and move libxml2 before the other libraries. You copied in /lib all the files in the /lib dir of the zip, did you?

Comment: Yes I did, and I tried moving the flags around as well, I tried libxml2.lib and libxml2_a.lib neither work unfortunatly, I have a backup of all my bins, includes, and libs that came with Pelles C and a backup of the default files plus the ones I added from libxml2.

Answer (score 0):

I once used Mini-XML. It compiles with ANSI C compilers.
http://www.minixml.org/

However you should be careful because parsing HTML is not the same as parsing XML. For instance, in HTML you can have tags without closing them. Eg:

```
<img src="foo.jpg">
```

Comment: in that case I am looking for html is there an html parser library for windows?

Answer (score 0):

I tried a tool called html2cxx could parse html. It can parse html and css1.0 well though has not been updated for some years.

Comment: If you want the parser robust, I think you should look into webkit's source code.